# Mean Stack - Using Express to Send all Static Content for AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am have made a few apps with node and have used Angular on a few front ends, but i have never combined the two. I am total loss for how to send all the views to the front end when index.html is sent. Currently i have the following code in my server:

```
...
app.use(express.static('./app'));
app.listen(config.port, function() {
   logger.info('Server listening on ' + config.port);
}); 
....

 app.get('/update', auth.isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
     byo.userUpdate(res);
 })

app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');//'/public/index.html');
})
```

/////////

```
HTML Template:

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
<!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.scss">
<link rel="stylesheet"        href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js">   </script>
<!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="uptimeApp">


<!-- Add your site or application content here -->
<div class="header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
       <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
         <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
               <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
               <span class="icon-bar">asdasd</span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               <span class="icon-bar"></span>
               </button>
               <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Uptime Robot</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
               <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                 <!-- <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li> -->
               </ul>
            </div>
        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
     </nav>


<div class="container">
    <!--- Main Angular VIEW -->
  <div ng-view></div>

</div>

<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span> from the support team</p>
  </div>
</div>




<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

    <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/byo.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

byo.js (was main.js):

```
 angular.module('uptimeApp')
 .controller('byoCTRL', function () {
 this.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
 ];
});
```

About.js:

```
 angular.module('uptimeApp')
 .controller('AboutCtrl', function () {
  this.awesomeThings = [
  'HTML5 Boilerplate',
  'AngularJS',
  'Karma'
  ];
});
```

app.js:

```
angular
.module('uptimeApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
 ])
 .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/byo.html',
    controller: 'byoCTRL',
    controllerAs: 'byo'
  })
  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
    controller: 'AboutCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'about'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });


  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });
```

//////

```
my static file structure is as such:
-app
--images
--scripts
 |-controllers
 |-service
 |-app.js (angular routing file)
--views
 |-byo.html
 |-about.html
--index.html
```

When i run my server and naviate to localhost:8080/ the index.html page loads as expected. When i check in dev tools, all css files and js files that are included in the html header/footer are included as expected. However, i do not see any additional html files anywhere. The index page is left with an empty body because the ng-view is not being loaded.

```
Angular routing:
...
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

$routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/byo.html',
    controller: 'byoCTRL',
    controllerAs: 'byo'
  })
...
```

I have the feeling i am missing something very basic but can't figure it out. After researching i found a lot of articles relating to templating engines but i would prefer not to use one(do i have to?). Any help is greatly appreciated and if there is any additional information i can provide please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your root view loaded `views/byo.html` please check the console network tab? Please add your index.html template.

Comment: No thats what i cant figure out. The index page(basically header/footer) appear just fine but the body which for '/' is byo.html, nothing is loading. I dont understand how to get that to the front end :(. My console tab is loading everything BUT the views folder.

Comment: Just add your base HTML template please. Have you check your network console tab? Is AngularJS firing a request to load `views/byo.html` ? Is there any error output in your console?

Comment: I am getting:
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/$injector/modulerr?p0=uptimeApp&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.5.7%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A163)
    at angular.js:38
    at angular.js:4631
    at r (angular.js:321)
    at g (angular.js:4592)
    at db (angular.js:4514)
    at c (angular.js:1751)
    at Bc (angular.js:1772)
    at ge (angular.js:1657)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:31468)
    at j (jquery.js:3148)

Comment: Ok please add your whole code of `app.js`, `main.js` & `about.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `byoCtrl` is unknown because of your resource loading order. Try switching your loading order so byo controller is available when ngRoutes config() hits.

```
<script src="scripts/controllers/byo.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Let your express application only send your index.html when you hit the root dir of your domain:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/app/index.html');//'/public/index.html');
})
```